# What is the expected value of $X := \min\{U,\frac{1}{2}\}$?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

Let $U: \Omega \to (0,1)$ be a random variable that is uniformly distributed on the unit interval $[0,1]$. Furthermore, let $X := \min\{U,\frac12\}$ and $X_n := 2^{-n} \lfloor 2^n X \rfloor$ for all $n \geq 0$.
Determine the expected value of $X$.

I know that in order to determine $E[X]$, I need $\lim_{n \to \infty} E[X_n]$. And for that, I need to know the distribution of each $X_n$.

However, I'm don't know how to determine those.
Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you determine the distribution for small $n$, such as 2 and 3?

Comment: X has a mixed distribution, its probability of being 1/2 is 1/2, and then it has a uniform distribution over the interval [0,1/2]. From that E(X) follows directly. So, I am not following why you have the X_n involved here. Please clarify. Is the distribution of X_n a separate question?

Comment: @eyeballfrog I'm not quite sure but I think since the range of values for $X_2$ is $\{0,\frac12,\frac14\}$, the distribution of $X_2$ should be as follows: $P[X \leq \frac12] = 1$, $P[X \leq \frac14] = 0.5$ and $P[X \leq 0] = 0$

Comment: @PonderStibbons In the assignment, we were told to "determine $\lim_{n \to \infty} E[X_n] = E[X]$", so I figured that we should calculate the expected value of $X$ using the limit of the expected values of the $X_n$'s

Comment: @mara If the rest of the assignment continues to make reference to $X_n$, then perhaps you are simply meant to calculate this directly and then use it later.

Comment: @WillR Actually, this is the last part of the assignment. The first parts of it are drawing the graph of the distribution function of $X$ and finding the range of value for each $X_n$.

Comment: X_n is X truncated in binary. When X=1/2, X_n=X, mostly. Otherwise X-X_n has a uniform distribution over [0,1/2^n] or there abouts, which makes is easy enough to compute.

Answer (score 5):

As a trick, you can use the fact that $\min(x,y)=0.5(x+y-|x-y|)$, then
$$\int_{[0,1]}\min\bigg(u,\frac{1}{2}\bigg)du=\frac{1}{2}\int_{[0,1]}\bigg(u+\frac{1}{2}-\bigg|u-\frac{1}{2}\bigg|\bigg)du= \\
=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\int_{[0,1]}\bigg|u-\frac{1}{2}\bigg|du\bigg)=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-2\int_{[0,1/2]}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}-u\bigg)du\bigg)= \\ = \frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-2\bigg(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{8}\bigg)\bigg)=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(1-\bigg(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\bigg)\bigg)=\frac{3}{8}$$

Answer (score 3):

Excuse the crudeness. And the verbosity required to get past the robot.

[image]

Comment: One may not like it, but this is what peak measure theory looks like